How do you solve $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln(\cos(x+y))\ dy dx$?
How do you solve $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln(\cos(x+y))\ dy dx$?
In my case, my approach is to use Jacobian Determinant by substituting
$u=x+y\; v=x-y$ in order to produce like this $\iint_R \ln(cos(u)) J(u,v) dudv$.

You can plug $x+y=u$ and $y=v$. When $x=0$ we get $y=u$, and when $x=\frac{\pi}2$ we get $\frac{\pi}2+y=u$. So $u$ ranges from $0$ to $\pi$ and $v$ ranges from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$. 
Now, the Jacobian is: $|Det(J)|=\text{abs}\left(\begin{vmatrix}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}&\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \
\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}&\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}
\end{vmatrix}\right)=\text{abs}\left(\begin{vmatrix}
1&1\ 0&1
\end{vmatrix}\right)=1$
$$ I=\int_0^\pi\int_0^\frac{\pi}2 \ln(\cos(u))dvdu=\frac{\pi}{2} \cdot\int_0^\pi \ln(\cos(u))du=\dots \square  $$

@Afield: Incorrect. The integration domain in the $(u, v)$ plane is not a rectangle, but a parallelogram $(0\leq v\leq\pi/2, v\leq u\leq v+\pi/2)$.

How are we supposed to interpret the logarithm of the negative arguments when the value of the cosine (in the triangle $x+y >\pi/2$) becomes negative? Which branch?

@metamorphy I am agree with his comment.

Mathematica says: $-\frac{7 \zeta (3)}{8}-\frac{i \pi ^3}{8}-\frac{1}{8} \pi ^2 \ln (4)$

Any idea how to solve it?

@ブライアン安室: (responding to your agreement) Well, integrate the constant function $1$ both ways (and compare the results).

@metamorphy My bad!

I'll consider only the integral over the lower triangular region $x+y\le \pi/2$ where the cosine remains positive,
not over the full square $0\le x,y\le \pi/2$, because
the OP did not specify what the interpretation of the logarithm is for negative real-valued arguments (principal value?):
$$
I\equiv \int_0^{\pi/2} dx \int_0^{\pi/2-x} dy \ln(\cos(x+y))
$$
Jacobian for $u=x+y$, $v=x$, $y=u-v$ is
$$
\left|\begin{array}{cc}
\partial x/\partial u & \partial x/\partial v \\
\partial y/\partial u & \partial y/\partial v \\
\end{array}\right|
=
\left|\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1 \\
1 & -1
\end{array}\right| = 1.
$$
The triangle in $(x,y)$ transforms into another triangle in $(u,v)$:
$$
I=\int_0^{\pi/2} du \int_0^u dv \ln(\cos u)
$$
$$
=\int_0^{\pi/2} du u \ln(\cos u)
$$
Substit. $u=\pi/2-t$
$$
I= - \int_{\pi/2}^0 dt (\pi/2-t) \ln(\sin t)
= \int_0^{\pi/2} dt (\pi/2-t) \ln(\sin t)
$$
$$
=  \pi/2
\int_0^{\pi/2} dt \ln(\sin t)
-\int_0^{\pi/2} dt t \ln(\sin t)
$$
The first integral is the sum of integrals 4.384.9 and 4.384.10 in
the Gradsteyn-Ryzhik tables, see https://oeis.org/A173623
$$
I=  \pi/2 (-\frac{\pi}{4}\ln 4) -\int_0^{\pi/2} dt t \ln(\sin t)
$$
The second integral has a known value, the absolut value registered in https://oeis.org/A173624
which contains the derivations
$$
I=  -\frac14 \pi^2 \ln 2 +[\frac18 \pi^2 \ln 2 -\frac{7}{16}\zeta(3)]
$$
$$
=-\frac{7}{16}\zeta(3)-\frac{\pi^2}{8}\ln 2 \approx -1.38103595\ldots
$$
